# Why margin-top should not be used in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

OK, this might be a really funny yet stupid question even when I think of it when asking.

I think I read/listen it in one of the courses in Lynda.com that Bootstrap 4 *does not work well with margin-top*. I'm confused where I read it. And, that single sentence has shaped my web career to not use margin top anytime I use Bootstrap.

I prefer using margin-bottom on all of my components whenever I need a margin-top on the element coming after it. Now, I do not know how correct this theory is.

Hence, I would like to know if this theory is true. As a beginner, it's good to question every confusion you have and get to the core of the problem; rather than avoid it and never discover it.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<!-- I need margin top on second column, but I'm using it on first column with bottom margin right now. It works and solves the problem. But the question of why always remain. -->
  <div class="col-12 mb-5"></div>
  <div class="col-12">I need margin top here. But I'm going to put it in above column using margin-bottom :D</div>
  
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2-3 weeks of searching, I have finally found the answer I was looking for. And, let me tell you, I didn't expect this to be the answer at all.

Bootstrap 4 uses Reboot to reset the CSS stylesheet.

> Reboot does a few things differently. It is based on Normalize. It
>   avoids margin-top , embraces the CSS inherit value, uses the rem unit
>   heavily, and embraces the use of native font stack for optimum text
>   rendering.

[View Full Article Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/bootstrap-4-everything-you-need-to-know-c750991f6784)

And, it seems that was the answer I found out! I hope some people who look later down the road understand it that it was a Design decision, much of which I love to follow now! And, you can make your decision as well.